# LINQ join lambda syntax - need to translate this from query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, join, lambda

I've been banging my head on this one for about 2 days now.

I have a really advanced SQL Server query that I need translated to LINQ.

It involves:

- 6 inner joins
- A select that includes columns from each of the tables
- A specific groupby that involves a ton of columns from each table.

I also need to be able to dynamically build a where clause predicate (using predicatebuilder), so if I want the where clause applied in the correct spot, I think I need to use lambda expressions (after much trial and error).

Here is the part that I'm having a very difficult time translating:

```
var query = from order in orders                         
            join customer in customers on order.CustomerID equals customer.ID
            join ordersection in ordersections on order.ID equals ordersection.OrderID
            join ticket in tickets on ordersection.ID equals ticket.OrderSectionID
            join evt in events on ticket.EventID equals evt.id
            join client in clients on evt.ClientID equals client.id
            join venue in venues on evt.VenueID equals venue.VenueID
```

Thanks so much for your time (in advance)!

Comment: Is the current query posted with `Joins` working, or you want solution for this too

Comment: There's no actual question here. This is just a bunch of statements. You should read [ask]. We need to have something concrete to work with and a clear problem to solve.

Comment: @Enigmativity, indeed more time is spent in understanding the question, than devising a solution

Comment: Not sure if you own database or not. It's better to implement this query as view and query from that view in LINQ. SQL query is much maintainable than LINQ in such case.

Comment: What you show doesn't need translating to LINQ. It *is* LINQ. And it's the syntax --query syntax-- that's most suitable for joins. There's no point in translating it to the far more clunky method syntax, if that's your question. Let the compiler do that for you. So what exactly is your question when it come to translating? As for building a dynamic where clause, look for "predicate builder + LINQ" and take your pick from numerous hits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is the `Linq` version of your query as expected:

```
var query = orders.Join(customers, o => o.CustomerID, c => c.ID, (o, c) => new { o, c })
                       .Join(ordersections, o => o.o.ID, os => os.OrderID, (o, os) => new {o = o.o, c = o.c,os})
                       .Join(tickets, o => o.os.ID, t => t.OrderSectionID, (o, t) => new {o = o.o, c = o.c,os = o.os,t})
                       .Join(events, o => o.t.EventID, e => e.id, (o, e) => new {o = o.o, c = o.c,os = o.os,t = o.t,e})
                       .Join(clients, o => o.e.ClientID, cl => cl.id, (o, cl) => new {o = o.o, c = o.c,os = o.os,t = o.t,e = o.e,cl})
                       .Join(venues, o => o.e.VenueID, v => v.VenueID, (o, v) => new {o = o.o, c = o.c,os = o.os,t = o.t,e = o.e,cl = o.cl,v});
```

Final Result / Schema of `query` is an anonymous type consisting of `order,customer,ordersection,ticket,evt,client,venue`, which you may want to transform into typed entity / DTO.

In this case we are projecting the result of every join and taking forward complete objects instead of few properties

Comment: Note that you don't need all the names in `o = o.o` etc - just `new { o.o, o.c, o.os etc }` would work fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for the information, I thought this might lead to multiple levels of referenced access

Comment: No, it's exactly the same - it just infers the name from the expression used to initialize it.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj thank you very much! This was the perfect solution and worked brilliantly. Thank you Jon also!

Answer (score 0):

The [Mrinal Kamboj answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39927754/linq-join-lambda-syntax-need-to-translate-this-from-query/39929657#39929657) already shows how you can translate the sample query syntax to method syntax. However, that's not strictly necessary because you can achieve the same by simply adding anonymous type projection at the end, and then perform the rest (dynamic filtering, final projection) on that:

```
var query =
    from order in orders                         
    join customer in customers on order.CustomerID equals customer.ID
    join ordersection in ordersections on order.ID equals ordersection.OrderID
    join ticket in tickets on ordersection.ID equals ticket.OrderSectionID
    join evt in events on ticket.EventID equals evt.id
    join client in clients on evt.ClientID equals client.id
    join venue in venues on evt.VenueID equals venue.VenueID
    select new { order, customer, ordersection, ticket, evt, client, venue };

query = query.Where(dynamicFilter);
...
```